# How to insert user access missing records for the user

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

I am trying to insert user access missing record. I have used Exist statement to get the missing record. But we are facing problem when user is Granted access then revoked and then granted for same project.

GRANT ->REVOK->GRANT

In this case we cant able to get the record. Since we already have revoke access listed for that user in table.

Kindly advise

query :

```
   SELECT Getdate() [RequestedDate],
   Getdate() [ApprovedDate],
   A.requestedfor,
   '1234'    [ApprovedBy],
   A.ProjectNo,
  
   'Revoke'  [AccessRequestType]

FROM   [dbo].[projectaccessrequests] A
WHERE  A.requestedfor = 123
   AND A.accessrequesttype = 'Grant'
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   [dbo].[projectaccessrequests] B
                   WHERE  B.requestedfor = 123
                          AND B.accessrequesttype = 'Revoke'
                          AND Isnull (A.projectno, 0) =
                              Isnull (B.projectno, 0)
                          )
```

Comment: Could you show some example data to illustrate the question a little?

Comment: i have added the pick. In that you could see for Project TEST1 the user has GRANT access on 14 OCT 2015 and the access has been REVOKE on 19APR2016. but user again get access for the same project on 03OCT2016. Since the user is already have REVOKE entry NOT EXISTS is not able to get record for this project no

Comment: You need to check for the max(date) too, the last record being revoke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the following condition in NOT Exists to fix the issue

A.RequestedDate < B.RequestedDate